# jq: output structure, shortening array, preserving the other fields in the input

Tags: jq

For a JSON file like this:

```json
{
  "mylist": [...],
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

with `mylist` containing many elements, how can I output the same JSON structure, but with only the first N elements in `mylist`?

I was trying to use `jq '.mylist[:N]'`, but this prints the first N elements of `mylist` without the other fields such as `foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of re-creating the whole object again, you could just update `|=` that one field:

```bash
jq '.mylist |= .[:N]'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/c68B44YbJ4V)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to apply this filter:

```bash
jq '.mylist = (.mylist[:N])'
```

This filter:

- creates a copy of `mylist` from the input, taking the first `N` elements
- assigns this to the `mylist` field in the input
- outputs the result